# react dependency issue while npm install

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

Could not resolve dependency:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: webmin-react@0.1.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from react-native-typography@1.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-typography
npm ERR!     react-native-typography@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native@0.68.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from react-native-typography@1.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-typography
npm ERR!     react-native-typography@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-06T06_23_11_824Z-debug-0.log
```

this text from log

127 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
127 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1398:25)
127 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1391:30)
127 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1332:11)
127 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:950:11)
127 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)
127 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
127 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
127 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:156:5)
127 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:66:5)

## and this is error report.txt

```
While resolving: webmin-react@0.1.1
Found: react@16.14.0
node_modules/react
  react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
  peer react@"*" from react-native-typography@1.4.1
  node_modules/react-native-typography
    react-native-typography@"^1.4.1" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native@0.68.0
node_modules/react-native
  peer react-native@"*" from react-native-typography@1.4.1
  node_modules/react-native-typography
    react-native-typography@"^1.4.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "react",
    "version": "16.14.0",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "webmin-react",
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "path": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/react",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "^16.14.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "peer",
        "name": "react",
        "spec": "*",
        "from": {
          "name": "react-native-typography",
          "version": "1.4.1",
          "whileInstalling": {
            "name": "webmin-react",
            "version": "0.1.1",
            "path": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
          },
          "location": "node_modules/react-native-typography",
          "isWorkspace": false,
          "dependents": [
            {
              "type": "prod",
              "name": "react-native-typography",
              "spec": "^1.4.1",
              "from": {
                "location": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "^16.14.0",
    "from": {
      "location": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "react",
    "spec": "17.0.2",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "react-native",
      "version": "0.68.0",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "webmin-react",
        "version": "0.1.1",
        "path": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/react-native",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "react-native",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "name": "react-native-typography",
            "version": "1.4.1",
            "whileInstalling": {
              "name": "webmin-react",
              "version": "0.1.1",
              "path": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
            },
            "location": "node_modules/react-native-typography",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "prod",
                "name": "react-native-typography",
                "spec": "^1.4.1",
                "from": {
                  "location": "F:\\Download's\\react\\webmin-react"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like react-native had not updated its peer-dependency of react yet from 17x to 18x. If you take a look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/41cbccd98dd6c98d1f662674164cf455105a1359) comment then you'll see it's done now. So try installing again because now it should work.

And if it doesn't you can always use the `force` flag. But only use this flag as a last resort.